# Problem with asp.net regular field validations

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I want to validate 14 digits National ID number so i use the following validator :

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="You Must Enter 14 digits" Display="Dynamic" id="RegularExpressionValidator1{generate-id()}" Font-Bold="True" ControlToValidate="ff1_1" validationexpression="[0-9]{14}" />
```

but it is not working as expected.refer below error, it is a valid number:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: i checked and it is working as expected.

Comment: I checked too and it's fine ? Can you tell us what this is - `id="RegularExpressionValidator1{generate-id()}`- this is not valid asp.net webforms markup